# Analysis of Kullback-Leibler divergence

Tags: information-theory

Let us consider the following two probability distributions

```
P       Q
0.01    0.002
0.02    0.004
0.03    0.006
0.04    0.008
0.05    0.01
0.06    0.012
0.07    0.014
0.08    0.016
0.64    0.928
```

I have have calculated the Kullback-Leibler divergence which is equal $0.492820258$, I want to know in general what does this number shows me? In general Kullback divergence shows me how far is one probability distribution from another right? It is similar to entropy terminology, but in terms of number, how can I  say  let says result is 0.49 can i say that  approximately  one distribution is far from  another by by 50%? or? thanks in advance

Comment: any help please?

Comment: Please don't crosspost  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/106327/kldiv-kullback-leibler-or-jensen-shannon-divergence-between-two-distributions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i have have calculated kullback-leibler divergence which is equal 0.492820258

1. The KL divergence is not a dimensionless number, it has an unit (which depends on the base of the logarithm used), you must specify it unless it's implied by the context. I guess you used base `2`, hence the unit it *bits*.
2. The KL divergence (or "distance") is *not* symmetric: $D(p || q) \ne D(q|| p)$, so , again, you must specify which one you computed.

In our case $D(p||q)=0.49282$ bits.

Regarding the numerical significance, you could first compute the entropies. In our case $H(p)=1.9486...$ and $H(q)=0.5745...$ (always in bits). In terms of source encoding (first Shannon theorem), this says that source $p$ can be optimally encoded with $1.9486...$ bits per symbol. Now, if we encode source $p$ assumming (wrongly) that its true distribution were that of $q$, we'd get an average code length of $2.44142...$ bits per symbol (you can do the math). The "excess" error, the ineficciency that arises because of assuming a wrong distribution, is quantified by the KL divergence: $2.44142-1.9486=0.49282$ bits.

Comment: thanks for replay,yes i used  base two and D(p||q),sorry i have confused it means that it shows us  error of  mistakenly assuming  that some model is  from one distribution,while in really it is from another one?

Comment: and also how you have computed 2.44142 ?

Comment: @datodatuashvili I suggest you to care a little more about your typing: uppercases, punctuation, spaces (eg, after commas). Not only as a cortesy, but also to make your text easier to read.

Comment: @datodatuashvili That is one of the possible interpretations of the KL distance, yes. It's mentioned in any textbook, or in the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Motivation).

Comment: > how you have computed 2.44142? As $\sum_{x_i \in p} P(x_i) L_i $ where $L_i = -\log P^*(x_i)$ is the optimal length of the code for symbol $i$, compute from a probability function $P^*$ (in this case, from $q$)

Comment: please update your answer to see it clearly thanks in advance